# iterating over Zend_Paginator object for display

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect object from this query:

```
public function fetchPagedTracks() {

        $select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
                       ->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE);
        $select->join(array('ar' => 'artist'), 'ar.id = track.artist_id',
                array('artist_name' => 'name'));
        $select->join(array('al' => 'album'), 'al.id = track.album_id',
                array('album_name' => 'name', 'artist_id', 'year'));
        $select->order('artist_name', 'ASC');
        $select->order('album_name');
        $select->order('track', 'ASC');

        //create a new instance of the paginator adapter and return it
        $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);

        return $adapter;
    }
```

The data returns as expected and works, my issue is with my viewscript. I want to iterate over the result set in a specific way. Basically i want to have the artist at the top of a table with sub tables for each album with the tracks listed in each in order. I have accomplished this...but not properly, I had to do what I feel is a hack and I'm hoping SO can help me fix it.

Here is the view:

```
<?php
echo $this->paginationControl(
        $this->paginator, 'Sliding', '_paginatorControl.phtml'
)
?>
<table>
    <?php
    foreach ($this->paginator as $track):;
//     Zend_Debug::dump($track, '');
        $artist = $track->artist_name;
        $album = $track->album_name;
        ?>
        <?php if ($end_artist != $artist): ?>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4"><?php echo $track->artist_name ?></th>
            </tr>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if ($end_album != $album): ?>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4"><?php echo $track->album_name . ' ' . $track->year ?></th>
            </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Track #</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Bitrate</th>
            <th>Play Time</th>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $track->track ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $track->title ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $track->bit_rate . 'Kbps' ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->playtime($track->play_time) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $end_artist = $track->artist_name;
        $end_album = $track->album_name
        ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
<?php
echo $this->paginationControl(
        $this->paginator, 'Sliding', '_paginatorControl.phtml'
); ?>
```

The big issue is that this code causes two notices:

> Notice: Undefined variable: end_artist in
>   E:\www\home.local\application\modules\music\views\scripts\index\display.phtml
>   on line 13... and on line 18

The offending variables are `$end_artist` and `$end_album` and for life of me I can't figure out how to do this a different way. Suggestions?

P.S. a dump of the paginator object can be seen at [Pastbin](http://pastebin.com/b3mWsT5m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `$end_artist` and `$end_album` variables not defined before, put

```
$end_artist = '';
$end_album = '';
```

before `foreach`

Comment: I actually said "Oh Dam!"...Talk about missing the obvious thanks.